# How to return a value when using execute_script in capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

I have a really simple line in a test that calls execute script like this:

```
puts page.execute_script("return somefunction();").to_i.inspect
```

And in javascript I have a function like this:

```
function somefunction(){
    console.log("test");
    return 999;
}
```

The 'test' from the console log is getting logged out so it is running however...

Looking at the logs when running the test, the execute_script returns 0 not 999, so in rspec I can't get at the return value from the function, how do I make page.execute_script return that value from that function?

Comment: Which driver are you using? It appears to work with at least Selenium-Webdriver.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The Poltergeist driver is designed to return nil for [`execute_script`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/poltergeist/Capybara/Poltergeist/Driver#execute_script-instance_method):

```
def execute_script(script)
  browser.execute(script)
  nil
end
```

Poltergeist will only return a value if you use the [`evaluate_script`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/poltergeist/Capybara/Poltergeist/Driver#evaluate_script-instance_method):

```
def evaluate_script(script)
  browser.evaluate(script)
end
```

Capybara has corresponding methods for each - ie [`Session#execute_script`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#evaluate_script-instance_method) and [`Session#evaluate_script`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#execute_script-instance_method). Your code should work if you switch to using `evaluate_script` (and as @AndreyBotalov points out, you also need to remove the `return`):

```
puts page.evaluate_script("somefunction();").to_i.inspect
```

Comment: Note that this answer won't work with Selenium as Capybara would insert `return` itself.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov, I corrected the code to remove the `return` when using `evaluate_script`. Including the `return` will throw an exception for both Selenium and Poltergeist.