# Detecting javascript event handlers with Capybara

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, capybara

In my Rails app there is a whole lot of front-end js, and I'd like to check is a specific event is attached to a DOM element.

An example of the JS that adds the event is here:

```
$('.nextCard')[0].addEventListener('click',nextCard);
```

I'd like to write something like:

```
     expect(page).evaluate_script('​$._data( $(".nextCard")[0], "events" )').to eq('nextCard');
```

I know it's a bit cryptic, and I could test the JS separately ... but I would like to do all the testing with Ruby / Capybara if possible.

[How to return a value when using execute_script in capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956563/how-to-return-a-value-when-using-execute-script-in-capybara)

[Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state the event is added using plain DOM methods (addEventListener) there is no way (cross browser/unprivileged code) to enumerate the listeners.  However, if the handlers are attached via jQuery#on then you could check for the presence of a click handler with something like

```
expect(page.evaluate_script('​"click" in $._data( $(".nextCard")[0], "events" )')).to be true
```

That being said, what you're trying to do is not really a great idea, and will end up with really brittle tests.  What you should be doing in your feature tests is verifying the behaviors those click handlers facilitate work.