# how to instantly set/send_keys a textarea in capybara

Tags: selenium, capybara, saucelabs

I need to instantly fill a `textarea` with a very long `string` for testing purposes.

`set/send_keys` simulates typing and is too slow for `Sauce Labs` causing time outs.

Is there a way to instantly fill a `textarea` in `Capybara`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to instantly do it would be using `execute_script` to set the value via JS

```
element = find('textarea') # however you locate the element
execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', element, text_to_set)
```

Note: this won't trigger all the events a user would generate when inputting into the textarea

Comment: I would also emit the change event `arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` to make it like a copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks... I have tried that in the past but I keep getting `Failure/Error: execute_script('arguments[0].value = arguments[1]', textarea, long_text)

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)`

Comment: @dinky Update your Capybara - Parameter passing to execute_script was added in 2.12 . and being able to return elements from evaluate_script was added in 2.13

Comment: Gemfile.lock says I am using `capybara (= 2.7.1)`

Comment: @dinky That's over a year old -- upgrade to the latest release of Capybara

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that!

Comment: Worked with capybara 2.14.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Use Javascript/JQuery (`.val()` function) to set the field's `value` via the `.execute_script()`/`.evaluate_script()` function. It will automatically send the full string. You have more details bellow.

**Example:**

```
def execute_script(script)
  browser.execute(function() { 
    $('<yourSelectorHere>').val("blablabla"); 
  })
  nil
end
```

Selenium team decided a LOOOONG way back to make it work this way, because it will actually **simulate** the real way a user would fill that `input`/`textarea`/`field`/etc.

**Note:** I wrote the command in `WebdriverIO`, but now have updated to `Capybara` as well.

---

Indeed, using the `.setValue()`/`.set()`, or the `.keys()`/`.send_keys()` methods will issue a **POST** action on the target element (presumably an `<input>`) in the form of an array of characters. See example:

**Command:** `browser.setValue('input[connectqa-input="rename-device"]','stackoverflowstackoverflowstack');`

**Output:**

```
> browser.setValue('input[connectqa-input="rename-device"]','stackoverflowstackoverflowstack')
{ state: 'pending' }
> [21:52:25]  COMMAND   POST     "/wd/hub/session/3d830ffd-21c6-4e5f-a6b3-4f8a03821991/elements"
[21:52:25]  DATA                {"using":"css selector","value":"input[connectqa-input=\"rename-device\"]"}
[21:52:25]  RESULT              [{"ELEMENT":"6"}]
[21:52:25]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/3d830ffd-21c6-4e5f-a6b3-4f8a03821991/element/6/clear"
[21:52:25]  DATA                {}
[21:52:25]  COMMAND     POST     "/wd/hub/session/3d830ffd-21c6-4e5f-a6b3-4f8a03821991/element/6/value"
[21:52:25]  DATA                {"value":["s","t","a","c","k","o","v","e","r","f","(21 more items)"],"text":"stackoverflowstackoverflowstack"}
```

One quick and easy way to escape this is to go ahead and abuse the `.val()` JQuery function via the `.execute()`/`.executeScript()` methods:

**Command:** `browser.execute(function() { $('input[connectqa-input="rename-device"]').val("dwadawdawdawdawdawdwadawawdadawdawdaw"); })` (`WebdriverIO`)

For `Capybara` syntax, see this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956563/how-to-return-a-value-when-using-execute-script-in-capybara)**. It covers both `.execute_script()` & `.evaluate_script()`. (I don't want to mooch-off their views). Also you should document on the methods before-hand **[here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Selenium/Driver#evaluate_script-instance_method)**.

**Output:**

```
> [21:59:38]  COMMAND   POST     "/wd/hub/session/3d830ffd-21c6-4e5f-a6b3-4f8a03821991/execute"
[21:59:38]  DATA                {"script":"return (function () { $('input[connectqa-input=\"rename-device\"]').val(\"dwadawdawdawdawdawdwadawawdadawdawdaw\"); }).apply(null, arguments)","args":[]}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: @dinky from `conEmu`, or `GitBash` console. I was similating via `WebdriverIO`. I've setup a test-case with some inputs and stopped in debug more (`.debug()`). 
Due to the fact all drivers (`chromedriver`, `geckodriver`, etc) are implementing the [Selenium W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) standard, it should work the same on every framework that integrates with said drivers.

Comment: I got this: `> browser
VM3737:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1` from the chrome console

Comment: @dinky then update your question with your driver instantiation/declaration. Some snippet of code would help us pin-point the issue.